# What is Spaetzle? How is it cooked?

Tags: noodles, hungarian-cuisine, german-cuisine

We had Spaetzle for lunch today. I've never had Spaetzle and couldn't figure out the ingredients or cooking method.

Comment: `german-cuisine` hmph. It's called *galuska* or *nokedli,* and it's a vital part of Hungarian cuisine - can you image paprikás csirke without nokedli to accompany it?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59505/how-to-cook-spaetzle-german-homemade-noodles-pasta-without-it-ending-up-soggy?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spaetzle is basically a noodle. Throw together egg, flour and salt (maybe some water to thin it out) and force it through a mold. Anything with holes can be used as a mold (for instance, I've used my old metal colander and that would work fine). Once the dough is formed into little pieces (it doesn't usually hold together for long threads), put it in boiling water to cook for a few minutes and dress it to eat however you desire.

Note: some people say Spaetzle is a noodle, some say a dumpling, I have no preference, I just call it tasty!

Comment: I would like to say that with the right technique and [utensil](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A4tzlepresse) (Link in german, but the picture would suffice), it would form long threads. I would have to ask my girlfriend though, as I never did it myself.

Answer (score 5):

The ingredients are pretty similar to Italian egg pasta: wheat flour, eggs, salt, and water. The amount of eggs used is more, though, so that the consistency is that of a fairly thick batter instead of a dough. This batter is typically pressed through a coarse strainer into boiling water.

More details [at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A4tzle).

Comment: the other traditional way of cooking it is to place a small amount of batter on a wooden chopping board, tilt it towards the pot of boiling water, and sweep small 'lines' of batter into the pot with a flat knife.  This takes a lot of practice though: Spätzle-making devices are much easier!  They are delicious either way though.

Answer (score 4):

The methods listed here are good for making it. A simple dough forced into boiling, salted water. My grandmother Tauscher would make it, then drain and toss with some fresh farmstead butter and chopped fresh parsley or sometimes dill. Heavenly.

Answer (score 1):

My grandmother -in-law ( grew up in Austria) made the dough/batter as described ; then took a spoon and scooped bite size bits into a large pot of boiling water. She did this very fast , at a rate of about one pound of dough a minute. Later , she would fry them in goose grease with mild spices.

Comment: Call me a purist, but those are “Spatzen” - Austrian / Tyrolean cuisine, Spaetzle (actually Spätzle, but English has no ‘ä’, hence the transcription) are either strands / bands or bean-sized knobs.

Answer (score 0):

My grandmother would make this using a small amount of the dough and flattening with a fork, and then dredging it thru flower before putting into boiling chicken broth for our chicken noodle soup. She would also do the same technique and add to our potato soup.

Comment: While probably delicious, not what I would accept as “Spätzle”. And I am a native of “Spätzle Country” aka [Swabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swabia).